# Returning instance numbers, not values, of a dataset that passes a filter function

Tags: google-apps-script, filter

How do you write a filter function in GAS that, rather than returning values of a dataset that pass the condition, returns the instance numbers of the data that passes the condition?

For example, let's say our condition is divisibility by 10.

```
(value % 10 = 0)
```

And our dataset is

```
[1,5,10,20,7,40]
```

Items # 0, 1, and 4 fail the condition; items # 2, 3, and 5 pass.
Desired result:

```
[2,3,5]
```

---

EDIT: Cooper's answer below solves the problem as a single instance console command. In my Comments I have parsed his answer as a function that can take the array and condition as variables. For sake of better readability, I'll post that here:

```
function indicesOfEntriesPassingCondition (array,condition) {
 return array.map((value, i) => (condition(value))? i:'').filter(value => value !== '')
}

function testIndicesOfEntriesPassingCondition () {
  var condition = value => (value % 10 == 0);
  var array = [1,5,10,20,7,40]
  var results = indicesOfEntriesPassingCondition (array,condition);
  console.log(results)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function lfunko() {
  Logger.log([1,5,10,20,7,40].map((e,i) => (e % 10 == 0)? i: '').filter(e => e !== '').join(','))
}

Execution log
4:42:39 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:42:40 PM  Info    2,3,5
4:42:40 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: That's beautiful, and here it is parsed in GAS as a function that can take the array and condition as variables:
function indicesOfEntriesPassingCondition (array,condition) {
  return array.map((value, i) => (condition(value))? i:'').filter(value => value !== '').join(',')
}

Comment: Example: function testIndicesOfEntriesPassingCondition () {
  function condition (value) {return (value % 10 == 0)}
  var array = [1,5,10,20,7,40]
  var results = indicesOfEntriesPassingCondition (array,condition);
  console.log(results)
}

Answer (score 0):

### Alternate Solution

Try this code using simple JavaScript loop and indexOf:

```
function indexOfDivisibleByTen(){
  var arr = [1,5,10,20,7,40];
  var numberIndex = [];
  
  //loop through array to find those divisible by 10
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] % 10 ==0){
      //enter the index of the value in array instead of the actual value
      numberIndex.push(arr.indexOf(arr[i]));
    }
  }
  console.log(numberIndex);
};
```

Works the same as finding the value in the array but instead of entering the actual value into a new array, you enter the index or the position of the value from the array.

Result:
[image]

References:

- [JavaScript Looping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [JavaScript Array indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I just came back to revise my question because I forgot to emphasize the "function" part and say that I do know how to get the results via a loop, but this is one of those times when my gut tells me it isn't necessary to write a loop, that somewhere I read how to do this or something very similar with just one line of code, and it's driving my nuts that I can't remember what it was nor can I find it. Cooper's solution above is more like what I had in mind.

Comment: Sure! just leaving this answer as an alternate solution which is more basic and understandable for new programmers who don't know how to get the position in the array using indexOf. Thanks for response!